# How can we log user-bot conversations using the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: chat-bots

I am starting to create my first bot with Microsoft Bot Framework with the help of Azure, initially I want to know where all the conversations the user has with the bot are stored, so then get a log of all the conversations that have been held.

I already have some answers stored in knowledge bases using QnA Maker, for certain questions that you can answer, I want to know where the questions that were not answered or better that the bot could not answer are stored.

Currently, I am asking the users to write their question in a feedback form when they don't get a response from my bot. This is taking up my time and also annoys the user as they have to type more. I want my bot to collect these questions and store them in a database.

Comment: Leaving this open provisionally because although it may be slightly out-of-scope, it does relate to a practical matter related to AI development, and may be useful.